# Как уместить в 14 строк Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i = input('Ввести от 1 до 12')
# Нужно что бы при каждой цифре выводилось определенное значение к примеру при вводе 1 писалось бы 1,2,т.е
if i == 1: 
    print('Глава 1.2')
# и в конце
else:
    print('Выберите главу')
```

Но это все нужно уместить не более 14 строк кода.

Comment: Может поможет словарь? например `d = {'1':'Глава 1.2', 'a':'Другое значение'}` и дальше вызывать `print(d[input])`. Если например `input='1'` выведется `'Глава 1.2'`, а если `input='a'` выведется `'Другое значение'`
Словарь можно в одну строку написать.

Comment: i = input('Введите номер главы: )
if i = 1: print('Глава 1.1')
И так до 12 тобишь
if i = 12: print('Глава 1.12)
else: print('Введите номер главы от 1 до 12)

Comment: Как сказал @АндрейГригорьев, `dict` здесь - самое очевидное решение

Comment: @Alex, сделайте словарь `d={'1':'Глава 1.1' , '2':'Глава 1.2' ..., '12':'Глава 1.12'}`а чтобы проверить, есть ли ключ в словаре, надо спросить `if i in d:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {'1':'Глава 1.1', '2':'Глава 1.2', '3':'Глава 1.3', '4':'Глава 1.4', '5':'Глава 1.5', '6':'Глава 1.6', '7':'Глава 1.7', '8':'Глава 1.8', '9':'Глава 1.9', '10':'Глава 1.10', '11':'Глава 1.11', '12':'Глава 1.12'}
i = input('Ввести от 1 до 12')
if i in d:
    print(d[i])
else:
    print('Выберите главу')
```